# Xcode9.3 unit tests are getting stuck or behaving erratically

Tags: xcode, core-data, xctest

I've got some asynchronous Core Data tests that were previously on previous versions of Xcode but after I updated to Xcode9.3 they started behaving erratically. Sometimes they seem to get stuck right after the test "begins", at other times it crashes with strange errors like:

`NSInvalidArgumentException: Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship property = "log"; desired type = DiveLog; given type = DiveLog` // WTF?

I've already flagged a bug report with apple. Has anyone else experienced this issue and have you found a workaround?

Cheers,
Danny